# Interpolate 2D grayscale image from just handful of points

Tags: python, image, scipy, interpolation

I have an image that has only a handful of defined points, and the rest are NaN. I need to reconstruct all the pixels. Interpolating with interp2d seems like the way to go, but there is an open issue: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/1682
As far as I can tell, the NaNs explode this way, which would effectively "eat" all the solitary points.

Is there an easy solution for this?

Comment: You should post a MWE with some example data, but I am reasonably sure that all you need to do is to not pass the NaN values in when you are initialise the `interp2d` function.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be quite easy in the end:

```
def interpolate_image(rgbd, method='linear'):
    locs = np.where(~np.isnan(rgbd))
    vals = rgbd[~np.isnan(rgbd)]
    grid = np.mgrid[0:rgbd.shape[0],0:rgbd.shape[1]]
    return griddata(locs, vals, grid.T, method='linear')
```

One caveat is that the extrapolation is not working, so there could be persisting NaNs near the borders.